# Write csv file dynamically to servlet response OutputStream

Tags: java, servlets

I've more than 1 million data in DB. I need to read from DB 1000 rows at a time and write it to OutputStream until there is no data returned. I'm not sure how much data can be. So i don't know the length of the file until i reach the end of data.

Is it possible that to write data to outputstream in batches which should be flown to network at same time. I'm trying to achieve here is avoiding out of memory. If i keep 1 million data in output stream it will go OOM. so to avoid OOM i'm trying to write the data to network and it should not hold in any JVM memory , it should write to network as soon as i get it. what i've written code so far is here.

Note: This is stand alone code.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String header = "Doc Timestamp,Internal DocID,DocType,Sender,Receiver,Routing Status,User Status,External DocID\n";
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+"File.csv"); 
    resp.setContentType("text/csv");

    OutputStream stream = resp.getOutputStream();
    stream.write(header.getBytes());
    stream.flush();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        String docTimeStamp = new Date().toString();
        String docid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String docType = "ICSCSRin";
        String sender = "ACC15796_CWS";
        String receiver = "ACC15794_CWS";
        String routingStatus = "DONE W/ ERRORS";
        String userStatus = "CWS POST_PROCESS";
        String snrf = "CWS_TES";
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        str.append(docTimeStamp).append(",").append(docid).append(",").append(docType).append(",").append(sender).append(",").append(receiver).append(",").append(routingStatus).append(",").append(userStatus).append(",").append(snrf).append("\n");
        stream.write(str.toString().getBytes());
    }
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Due to HTTP protocol normally providing the size of the response before sending it, in such a case it will detect that it cannot do that and use a slightly modified protocol for HTTP response (chunked-encoding.) But it does work. Not sure what you mean with the code being standalone. It doesn't contain a main() method, so it's not standalone.

Comment: The output stream is not kept in memory. Everything you flush into it is supposed to be read by the client or it blocks. But do flush from time to time.

Comment: @RealSkeptic flushing is supposed to be implicitly done when the buffer is getting full.

Comment: @kumesana yes, but you don't know what the size of the buffer is, and when that will happen. The real problem of http applications that do not send the Content-length header is time outs. Flushing at known points could help against that.

Comment: @RealSkeptic never been in a situation when that was the correct solution to a problem, but I suppose there may be some out there.

Comment: @kumesana so if i write flush everytime i.e. in the loop, the content will be written to network ? Correct me if im wrong.
Why i mentioned standalone is because, i'm not connecting to DB. I'm looping here.